# How can I add icon to div via Javascript

Tags: javascript, api, icons, addition, weather

I have little problem. I have no idea how can I insert icon to div. I take data from weather API and I wanna create my weather widget. This is part of my code:

```
  data.list.filter((value) => value.dt_txt.slice(0, 10) == date.toISOString().slice(0, 10) ? value : null).forEach(function(obj) {

          date_elements[i] += `<tr>
    <td>
    date: ${obj.dt_txt} </br>
    wind speed: ${obj.wind.speed}</br>
    pressure: ${obj.main.pressure}</br>
    temperature: ${obj.main.temp}</br>
    humidity: ${obj.main.humidity}</br>
    icon: ${obj.weather.icon}
    </td>
  </tr>`

        });
```

If I insert code like this:

```
console.log(data.list[0].weather[0].icon);
```

I see vlue of property my Icon but I don't know how can I add url icon to this.

Comment: How about you concatenate object values, instead of inserting them as string?

Comment: Well, maybe `weather` should be accessed inside loop as an array too, like `icon: ${obj.weather[0].icon}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure about your question but if your `data.list[0].weather[0].icon` is a URL string to the icon you want to append to the table row, why don't you try this:
change your the line before your `</td>` tag to `icon: <img src = "${data.list[0].weather[0].icon}">`

Comment: I've solved problem, thank You ! `icon: <img src="meteocons-icons/SVG/${obj.weather[0].icon}.SVG">`